# How can I download my chat history from PlayStation messages to a text file?

Tags: psn

I would like to save the chat history of one of my PSN message chats to a text file, preferably including message timestamps and the usernames of those who sent each message. Is there a way to do this with a PC or Mac? If not, how can I go about it (will I have to just take screenshots)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no export function for your chats, but you can access it via web browser just like any other text chat, including chat history, creating new chats and of course you can reply to existing conversations.

Just head over to [playstation.com](http://playstation.com) and log in with your PSN account. On the top right you'll find the chat menu.

[image]